# Suitable term for a group of missions

Tags: single-word-requests, collective-nouns

I'm designing a computer application for a client, and I'm looking for a good term to describe a *group* of missions.

I have, at the moment, a *single* mission containing a series of well-defined steps, but I need to be able to package up multiple missions for delivery to an entity responsible for allocating each mission to other entities, for execution in parallel.

I've had a look at the dictionaries suggested [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2574#2574) but, while they provide the plural form "missions", that's not really what I'm after.

I *have* come up with "mission set" but I was rather hoping for something a little more compact (i.e., a single word). Usage would be along the lines of:

> The workload manager is responsible for packaging up related missions into a single **mission set** and sending that through to the mission controller. That controller will then distribute each mission to a mission executor for parallel execution.

The "**mission set**" is the bit I'm trying to get a better term for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the missions related to a common goal or are they just packaged together because they happen to be ready for scheduling at the same time?

Comment: I believe the correct group noun here is "flock"

Comment: @Jim, yes, there is a common goal. The business defines an overall need for something (a certain amount of things process in under a certain time). The workload manager sends that through to the mission controller, and the mission controller activates enough parallel executors to meet the need.

Comment: "Schedule, n: a plan for carrying out a process or procedure, giving lists of intended events and times." @WeatherVane: that's not too bad. I see the times in a schedule as being more time points rather than durations but I suppose I *could* suborn its meaning :-) Make it an answer, you'll at least get an upvote from me, even if someone comes along later with something better.

Comment: @GArthurBrown: do you have a citation for that? I can't find *any* indication  that `flock` would be correct. In any case, if it's a collective noun, it would be "flock of missions" which is even *more* verbose than mission set.

Comment: In the military I think this would be a "campaign". I'm not sure how well that would fly in a civilian application.

Comment: I had the same reaction as @Barmar.  "Campaign" works well in a few contexts--military, election, advertising, etc.

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm saying, flippantly, there is no recognized collective noun for missions.

Comment: @GArthurBrown: I have no problem with humour but maybe think about putting a smiley on it next time so it's more obvious, and people don't unnecessarily expend effort on flippancy :-)

Comment: @Barmar (and cruthers), campaign's not too bad either. Makes my work sound *way* more important :-)

Comment: I also wonder about using the term "mission" for civilian tasks. But if you're going to use military jargon there, you might as well extend the metaphor.

Comment: As there is a common goal I think you could regard the collection of missions as a _project_. And the individual missions as stages in the project. Having said that if 'mission' describes a part or stage of the project better than 'stage' then the suggestion by @cruthers of 'campaign' would probably be more suitable.

Comment: Project, campaign, and schedule are all viable options but I can't give them useful upvotes unless they've answers rather than comments. I don't want to have to do that myself since the person that came up with them will not  receive the benefit. But I will, if they're not converted to answers in the next few days. Nudge Nudge Wink Wink :-)

Comment: The workload manager is responsible for **repackaging related missions** into a single mission. E pluribus unum, no? I would avoid package up.

Comment: I would stick with **set**, which is commonly used, unless you want something more fanciful, in which case I would look for or invent  something other than a common word similar to *set*. There is no point replacing *set* with, e.g., *batch*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the military world (and also *outside* the military), a set of missions with a common goal could be referred to as a ***campaign***:

> **campaign** *noun*
> **1** :a connected series of military operations forming a distinct phase of war.
> **2** : a connected series of operations designed to bring about a particular result.
>
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster —
> *campaign*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/campaign)</sub>

Examples:

- *The group launched a **campaign** to protect the area from commercial development.*
- *The university is organizing a **campaign** to attract a more diverse student population.*
- *The workload manager is responsible for packaging up related missions into a single **campaign** and sending that through to the mission controller.*

---

Note: I'm self-answering since three months is *more* than enough time for commenters to be given to convert their comments into answers as I suggested :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try *batch*:

> **batch** *noun*
> **2 c** : a group of jobs (such as programs) that are submitted for processing on a computer and whose results are obtained at a later
> time
>  <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster —
> *batch*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/batch)</sub>

Example:

> *The workload manager is responsible for packaging up related missions into a single **batch** and sending that through to the mission
> controller.*